# Getting issue while sending nested JSON as request to validate the POST REST API method using Karate framework

Tags: rest-api, karate

Please note that I am trying to send the below request and validate the response on POST method using url `http:*******

Note : I tried sending nested Json as an array like `****[0]='', voucherData[1]=''` etc but I got same error.

Comment: Can you please insert characters properly? Too many �

Comment: @YuZhang junk chars removed. It would be really appreciable if i get help on above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tip. Since you know the expected request structure, keep in mind that you can use it almost as-is in Karate. And proper JSON with double-quotes etc. is totally fine. And you can use the multi-line option. So please try this for the request step:

```
And request
"""
{
  "memberId":"******",
  "memberIpAddress":"******",
  "voucherData":{
     "******":{
        "voucherNo":"*****",
        "voucherValue":"***",
        "voucherIssueDate":"",
        "voucherExpiryDate":"******"
     }
  }
}
"""
```

And this should work ! Try it.

Comment: Sure Peter.will let you know asap the result

Comment: I saw this is the difference between Karate and Rest Assured that Karate uses data in single quote . Karate vs Rest Assured 
No need to use double-quotes or “escape” characters.@Peter please note that when i used escape sequence it got success but using single quote threw bad request.

Comment: Well, ok. I have no idea what you are referring to without an example or better details, but I am glad that something is working for you now. All the best !